# how to create java regx for below string

Tags: java, regex

I have files which named with `abc_abc0006_2012-11-26_1420_2121.11182012.zip` so i want to search all the files which start with `wei_wei0006` and ends with `.zip` and in between this it will contains only numbers, dates, and allow `-._` string. any one has how to do it using reg x, i have got one `^abc_abc0006_[0-9-._]+.zip$` which is not working. any idea?

I have tested below one it working fine but it has one problem it is picking up below type of files also.

solution is: `"abc_abc0006_*.zip"`
Results:

- op1:  `abc_abc0006_2012-11-26_1420_2121.11182012.zip`
- op1:  `abc_abc0006_2012-12-02_1321_some_alfhabet_text_20121202.zip`

valid result should pick below file only 
`abc_abc0006_2012-11-26_1420_2121.11182012.zip`

Comment: You mean `abc_abc0006_.*.zip`, right? Otherwise I suspect you're not actually using a regex.

Comment: yes that is right, i am using Talend ETL tool to get file list based on above regular expression. Talend is code generator so it will convert all the logic into Java code eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Try `^abc_abc0006_[-0-9._]+\.zip$`.

Or less magically, `^abc_abc0006_[0-9\-._]+\.zip$`. Your problem is that `-` has special meaning inside a character class and you need to escape it somehow.

Comment: If `-` is first or last it also loses its special meaning

Comment: @Bohemian: Yes, as you can see in my first version. You can either implicitly escape it by placing it first/last, or explicitly escape it with `\ `.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "-" at the end

> ^abc_abc0006_[0-9._-]+\.zip$

Comment: i think . is for any character in regex, not for '.'

Comment: @vishal_aim: Normally yes, but it doesn't mean that inside a character class.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
"abc_abc0006_[\\d_.-]+\\.zip"
```

If it's not working, show us how you are using it. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: My car is not working either. You need to be more specific in order to get useful help. Also I just took a close look and had a `0` too much before the 6. See my updated answer.

Comment: i edited my question please see for more details, i tested again not fulling any file.

Comment: If it's not working like in my updated answer, you need to provide more context. The regex above will definitively match what you tell us you want it to match.

Comment: i tested again still it is not pulling mention file.

Comment: as said in my answer: **You need to show us how you are using the regex**, because the regex in my answer will match `abc_abc0006_2012-11-26_1420_2121.11182012.zip` and won't match `abc_abc0006_2012-12-02_1321_some_alfhabet_text_20121202.zip`, just like you wanted it.

Comment: `java.util.regex.Pattern fileNamePattern_tFileList_2 = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("abc_abc0006_*.zip");` this way i am using it

Comment: well, that's not the regex from my answer!! Your `*` only means that the number of underscores `_` at that position can be any.

Answer (score -2):

use the following regular expression. I checked and that is working correctly.

```
[[\\w]||[\\s]||[_]||[-]||[.]]*.zip
```

Comment: It's hard to read, it can contain whitespace (not allowed) and it can't contain numbers (mandatory). Also it may end with `Xzip` instead of `.zip` and match anyway, even though `.zip` is a requirement.

Comment: also, in java regex OR is written as `|` and not as `||` but I am not sure if that is even possible inside a character class.

Comment: it reading all the files which ends with `.zip` as i mention it should read the file which start with `abc_abc0006_` and should contain some dates, numbers and then ends with `.zip`

Comment: i want to read only this type of files. `abc_abc0006_2012-11-26_1420_2121.11182012.zip`